# VB.Net forms.show() issue

Tags: vb.net, winforms

first i work on visual studio 2008.

i have a form(frmOrdreEnCours) that call an another form(frmListe) on a button.click event .

frmListe has a ListBox where you can choose a thing and validate it,
But i was ask to add a button frmOrdreEnCours that do the exact same thing, but it had to choose a specific element and don't show the frmListe.

so i tried  to simulate a click but it doesn't works without the .show() Method
and obviously my client don't want a to see a opened window even for a second.

```
Private Sub BtnVracSup_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnVracSup.Click

    Dim ArlTraduction As ArrayList = New ArrayList
    ArlTraduction.Add(30163) 'Non-conformite operationnel - materiel
    ArlTraduction.Add(30168) 'Non-conformite opérationnel - autres
    Classes.Langues.Traduire(ArlTraduction)
    Dim FrmListe As New FrmListe(FrmListe.TypeListe.OperationnelMaterielBacSupp, ArlTraduction(0).ToString, ArlTraduction(1).ToString, NumOrdre)
    FrmListe.MdiParent = FrmParent
    Dim HideIt As Boolean = False
    FrmListe.Show() // i don't want this
    FrmListe.Visible = HideIt // i even try this
    FrmListe.BtnValider.PerformClick() // there's no .Click available

End Sub
```

Comment: just create a method in the first form to do what you want...the code will be very like that in the other click event

Comment: Don't try to automate your UI interactions.  If you have logic to perform, perform it in the code.  The UI is for *users* to invoke logic, not for the *code* to invoke logic.  Code can simply call methods.

Comment: An ArrayList?  Time to start using a `List<T>`.  But your sample code makes it look like you don't even need an enumeration to begin with.  Just two integer variables (or strings, since that's what you are passing to the form).

Comment: it's a seven years old big project i'm in since 1 month with so much issues i'm quite desparate, i tried to make a method but there so much calls everywhere right now i'm trying to create a method but it'll take time

Comment: You have to analyze and extract the code that runs from that form's button's click event and probably move it to a class that you can access.  We don't see enough of your code to help with that.  The short-cut is to just change the access modifier of your form's button method from private to public, then just call it: `FrmListe.btnValider_Click(Nothing, Nothing)`

Comment: This, my friend, is why UI and Business Logic should be separate.  If it's not too big a job, maybe you could take this as an opportunity to re-write some of the more clumsy elements of the existing project by introducing a separate Business layer.

Comment: i totally agree it's just my first job, and i'm still learning i never saw a solution with 43 projects before x), well thanks you guys i'm working on a method

Comment: yeah and i forget to tell you that i can't debug i have to generate an .exe and send it on the tablet ><

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PerformClick doesn't do anything, if target control's `CanSelect` is `false`.
And if control is not visible, CanSelect return `false`.

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Button.cs,845bec419ca23629

You need call event handler (like `BtnValider_Click`) directry, but I think that looks bad code.

If you implemented like below:

```
Public Class FrmListe

    Private Sub BtnValider_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnValider.Click

        ' Validation codes '

    End Sub
End Class
```

It's time to extract validation codes to another method.

```
Public Class FrmListe

    Private Sub BtnValider_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnValider.Click

        IsValid()

    End Sub

    Public Function IsValid() As Boolean

        ' Validation codes '

        Return True ' or Return False it is not valid '
    End Function
End Class
```

and you can call this like following:

```
FrmListe.IsValid()
```

If you can, I recommend that you consider implement IsValid method in another class, like following:

```
Public Class ListeValidator
    Public Function IsValid(type As FrmListe.TypeListe, traduction1 As String, traduction2 As String, numOrdre As Object)
        ' I dont know type of NumOrdre '
        ' validation code here '
    End Function
End Class
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: i try this but i have to adapt the code the first big problem is that i can't debug it works only on a tablet and i have to generate an .exe that i send via FTP every single line i wan't to change and i can't know where it doen't work because i can't debug x)

Comment: Thanks you it works well !